# Static field or Shared preferences for ad counter

Tags: java, android, admob, sharedpreferences

I use a counter available from any activity.(to calculate how often to show ads) How best to implement it? Shared preferences or static field? What are the advantages and disadvantages of these cases?

Comment: If your counter value is being used only for each session user visits your app then static field is a good option as it will only hold the value as long as your app is alive. But if you want the counter value to be used for the whole life time after installing your app then go for shared pref as it will hold the value until user clears app data or uninstalls the app. You can go for any approach based on your use case.

Comment: Static variable will flush with app close, and Preference stays. So go with Preference approach. If counter is too much frequent(really changing fast),  you can use additional variable and then save to Preference.